# can you self-reference callback code in a google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am still trying to figure out Google's script library stuff.  One limitation I have run into is callbacks.  It seems that you can't have a callback reference a library (even though that's where it originated) so you have to create a local callback that then calls the library callback.

Let me explain:

Library LIB_A:

```
/*
 Populates the drop-down menu on the sheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  var tenantMenu = ui.createMenu("Tenant")
  tenantMenu.addItem("Add Tenant", "showAddTenantDialog")
  topMenu.addSubMenu(tenantMenu)
  topMenu.addToUi()

function showAddTenantDialog() {
...
}
```

In the code that imports LIB_A, for this to work it seems that I **have** to have:

```
/* This function is called by the sheet when it is opened.  I understand why this is required */
function onOpen() { 
  /* create the menu */
  LIB_A.onOpen()
}

/* Callback from the menu (that is actually in LIB_A) */
function showAddTenantDialog() {
  /* Call the intended function that resides in LIB_A */
  LIB_A.showAddTenantDialog()
}
```

I would really like to have my LIB_A code look something like this:

```
tenantMenu.addItem("Add Tenant", "LIB_A.showAddTenantDialog")
```

so I only have to have this in the code that imports LIB_A.

```
function onOpen() {
  LIB_A.onOpen()
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to call code in the importing file from a callback in the library

Comment: Actually, I am already doing this as shown above.  I was hoping for a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: According to this bug report, it cannot be done ?!? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197664258

Comment: Well, that report only says that Issue Tracker isn’t for coding questions, but for bug reports. That said, I think that what you’re doing is the way it has to be done. Assuming you wrote that bug report, however, if you want to use the same script seamlessly in multiple spreadsheets, would an add-on be a solution?